# In AngularJS, how can I "bind" the text in a span to a text box, and update it when I click on the span?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

The simplest version of my question is this:  I have a few spans:

```
<span id="one">SpanOne</span>
<span id="two">SpanTwo</span>
<span id="three">SpanThree</span>
```

and a text field:

```
<input type="text" id="textField"/>
```

I want to click on one of the spans, and have the text field populated with its text.  I can do something like adding 'onClick="document.all.textField.value=this.text"' to the span elements, but how can I do it using AngularJS?

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm going about it the right way, so I thought I'd ask a "clean slate" question.  But I have tried putting the same ng-model on the spans and the text field, and also adding an ng-click attribute to the spans, and neither worked.

Comment: @ToddMotto This is a basic example of Angular and he's just starting.  You sound like you don't even know Angular.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming your AngularJS enviornment is setup properly, the simplest way:

```
<span id="one" ng-click="myVar = 'SpanOne'">SpanOne</span>
<span id="two" ng-click="myVar = 'SpanTwo'">SpanTwo</span>
<span id="three" ng-click="myVar = 'SpanThree'">SpanThree</span>
<input type="text" id="textField" ng-model="myVar" />
```

---

@KayakDave has the best overall solution, in my opinion:

HTML:

```
<span id="one" ng-click="updateVar($event)">SpanOne</span>
<span id="two" ng-click="updateVar($event)">SpanTwo</span>
<span id="three" ng-click="updateVar($event)">SpanThree</span>
<input type="text" id="textField" ng-model="myVar" />
```

Your controller:

```
yourApp.controller('yourController', function ($scope) {

    $scope.updateVar = function (event) {
        $scope.myVar = angular.element(event.target).text();
    };

});
```

By doing it this way, if you change the text within the span than you wouldn't have to change anything in the `ng-click`.

You should ask KayakDave to post an answer, which he is is more than welcome to copy my demonstration of his suggestion, and than accept that.

Comment: This is how I tend to do it if you're only doing a single '=' operation.  This is probably the simplest way of doing it.

Answer (score 4):

I prefer put the logic inside the controller

In your html:

```
<span id="one" ng-click="updateVar('SpanOne')">SpanOne</span>
<span id="two" ng-click="updateVar('SpanTwo')">SpanTwo</span>
<span id="three" ng-click="updateVar('SpanThree')">SpanThree</span>

<input type="text" id="textField" ng-model="myVar" />
```

In your controller:

```
/*...*/
$scope.updateVar = function(value) {
    $scope.myVar = value;
}
```

Comment: I prefer this route too, but sometimes use my example to keep my controller less cluttered.

Comment: You can make this even a bit more general by passing in the event: `ng-click="updateVar($event)"` and setting `myVar` based on that parameter (which I called `event`): `$scope.myVar = angular.element(event.target).text();`

Comment: Just to note if you write your code like via TDD this you don't actually need to see it in your browser to know it works.

Answer (score 0):

The other examples are too complicated, if they even work.  You just create a variable, and display it in the span.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/XPLpP/1/

HTML:

```
  <div ng-app="myApp">

<div ng-controller="myCtrl">

    <input type="text" ng-model="text" />

    <span> {{text }} </span>
</div>
```

CODE:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.text = "initial value";
});
```

Comment: Lol, my example is "too complicated", and Beterabba's example is probably the most widely used. The OP is asking how to click on the span on have the input reflect, your example is the opposite, the span reflecting the input value. And you're injecting `$rootScope` which is absolutely unnecessary.

Comment: copy & paste error, but point taken, reading comprehension fail on my part.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution:

```
<div data-ng-app>
    <input type="text" id="textField" ng-model="text"/>
    <span ng-click="text = 'SpanOne'">SpanOne</span>
    <span ng-click="text = 'SpanTwo'">SpanTwo</span>
    <span ng-click="text = 'SpanThree'">SpanThree</span>
</div>
```

And the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/jeremylikness/G74wB/

If you want to bind to something on scope it would look like:

```
<span ng-click="text = variable">{{variable}}</span>
```